# How do I conditionally render a navbar in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nav, react-router-dom

How can I conditionally render a nav bar in React Router 5?
so far I've got this in my `<Router>`

```
{window.location.href.includes('data-url') ? null : (
    <CONNECTED_NAV />
)}
```

which does work but with one issue. I have a link in my `data-url` component which redirects back to the app. but once it redirects back and lands on another route `/home` then the nav bar is still not showing and I've consoled logged in the `<Router>` component and it's not re-rendering so that's why it's not showing.

is there a better way to force an update? or how to conditionally render a navbar?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your navbar to show up on the `/home` page only then you have to specify a route:

```
<Route exact path="/home" component={CONNECTED_NAV} />
```

This way the navbar will be only visible when the URL matches `/home` 
But if you want to show the navbar conditionaly on the homepage then you can also do that by replacing `component` with `render`

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={() => (condition ? <CONNECTED_NAV /> : null)} />
```

Route must be wrapped in BrowserRouter if you don't know about these maybe please visit
[React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on [@ahmad-nawaz-khan solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61965636/11317072)

You may still want to pass in the router props from react-router

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={(routerProps) => (condition ? <CONNECTED_NAV {...routerProps} /> : null)} />
```